# Animate to text height (autolayout)

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, autolayout

I want to animate from a height of 0 to the height of the text (UILabel). I am using autolayout and I do not know how high the text will be. My approach was to start by setting a height=0 constraint to the text, and animate like this:

```
//retrieves the height constrain of the clicked item
NSLayoutConstraint *heightContraint = [heightConstraints objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
//activates/deactivates the constraint
heightContraint.active = !heightContraint.active;
//animates
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

My problem is, that with this approach, the text height does not animate, it changes from a height of 0 to the new height instantly. Only the position/size change of the containing views is animated. How I animate the text height change without knowing the height of the text??

Comment: try to call layoutIfNeeded for that specific view inside block

 [weakSelf.sampleView layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: Does the animation occurs when you set some exact value for constraint? Just to distinct measurement and animation issues.

Comment: @Akeara I tried calling `[heightContraint.firstItem layoutIfNeeded];` instead, but I got the same result. I think the problem is related to the fact, that it animates a BOOL `heightContraint.active`, but it can't really do it since its values are only YES and NO (similar to when animating the isHidden property instead of using the opacity)

Comment: @VChemezov as you can see in the code, I only change the active state of the height=0 constraint.

Comment: Could you use `NSString`'s `-boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` for determining the height?

Comment: @Azat I'm using autolayout, so that would be a rather error-prone approach.

Comment: The purpose of autolayout is automatically calculate the frames of views, but you want do exactly the opposite. And do you think that `UILabel` internally determine its size using different approach than that in public API?

Comment: @Azat I don't want to know the size of the text. I just want it to animate from not showing the text to showing the text completely. It is possible, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Instead of setting a constraint to the height, I set a containing view (clipping), which contains the UILabel and the view above. Then, I create 2 constraints that pin the bottom edges to the containing view, one related to the UILabel, and one related to the view above. I just activate/deactivate those constraints like this:

```
//get the constraints
NSLayoutConstraint *viewAboveTextConstraint = 
        [viewAboveTextConstraints objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
NSLayoutConstraint *uilabelContraint = [uilabelContraints objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
//flip the active states
viewAboveTextConstraint.active = !viewAboveTextConstraint.active;
uilabelContraint.active = !uilabelContraint.active;
//animate
[UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{           
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```